# Use Similar to Apex:Repeat in non-visualforce HTML email template

Tags: email, html

Is it possible to have a similar repeat component in a non-VisualForce email?

I'm trying to generate a list of objects in a HTML email template. I know how to do it in VisualForce through components but I was wondering if I can do the same in a HTML email template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. HTML templates only support standard [formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm), and of those, only those that make sense in context. It doesn't have support for advanced scripting like loops, variables, and other stuff you have in Visualforce.